# android SherlockFragmentActivity - how to save values for a further start of the same activity

Tags: android

I am using the awesome ActionBarSherlock library for my app which runs with minSdkVersion 8.

The last bit I have to learn is how to save values for further calls of the same SherlockFragmentActivity (without the activity been destroyed in between)

All I tried so far doesnt seem to work

- setRetainInstance() is not supported in the underlying support library
- onRetainNonConfigurationInstance -> Cannot override the final method from FragmentActivity
- onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance doesnt seem to be called

I hope I oversee something easy. Basically i want to store some values so I can retain a state when the user clicks the home button (action menu up..) How to go about this?

Thanks a lot

martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply save the information about your activity state to permanent storage. I'd recommend looking into [sharedpreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Also the `setRetainInstance()` **IS** supported by the current underlying support library (r7) for ABS.

Comment: Thanks Warpzit. I am afraid that doesnt do for me as I dont want the values to be used when for example the user switches off the phone and starts the app again later. I just would like it within the flow of one usage of the app

Comment: @dorjeduck But you shouldn't have to do anything in order for the activity to stay the same... if you activity isn't closed the current state is retained.

Comment: When I go back to the activity with the back button all is there yet when I call it a second time with startActivity the values in EditText etc are gone. From my understanding that is what onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is all about but it doesnt seem to work with the support library and ListFragments - yet for sure I might just mix everything up right now ...

Comment: you can save the content of that EditText when the corresponding activity is destroyed and check when the activity is created if you have some saved content to load.

Comment: thanks Teovad for the suggestion, yet as mentioned, I am interested in in the case without the activity been destroyed in between . Warpzit I just checked with a small demo app, EditText values etc are not saved by default if you start in Activity the second time

Comment: just see the part "Also the setRetainInstance() IS supported by the current underlying support library (r7) for ABS." I am using v4 so far so I will try this, thanks

Comment: @dorjeduck you are right about the edittext, for that you'll have to save the content of the edittext. You could use sharedpreference and then just overwrite the content of the sharepreference on the fragment/activities onDestroy event.

Comment: thanks once more Warpzit, this is what I came up also, using sort of temporary sharedpreferences which works fine. I deleted them onCreate of the application object yet I think better to do as you said using the onDestroy event (even so we cant be sure if this method is called right?) so thanks seems a bit of a workaround yet a working one

Comment: @dorjeduck but the way you use the edittext is not the usual way to use edittext, all OS will work against you if you don't use them how they are intended to.

Comment: sorry for not being clear what you mean, in which way do i work against the usual way of edittext - what i have is the following: the top level activity is a list with a search field (which is the edit text) when the user searches in the list, clicks an item and does whatever he does yet at one point uses the actionbar to go back to the top level activity then i want the search text still to be there - how to achieve this if not like we discussed here?

Comment: @dorjeduck The way you are doing it is correct, I was only saying normally you'd just go back to the activity/fragment and expect the search field to be blank ready for a new search. BUT your way of doing it will probably suit some users better :)

Comment: thanks Warpzit - the reason I have chosen to "preserve" the search term  is just that deleting the search term is only a touch on the clear button the search field has while adding it again involves more work ... havent checked yet what the design guidelines recommend